# monitoring hardware

Tags: linux, monitoring, hardware, laptop, input

I have a laptop with a fingerprint reader that is currently doesn't seem to be supported by linux (integrated in lenovo yoga 920).

But I am quite curious if it is at all possible for me to listen to events from it so that I might be able to do *something* with it. Totally not expecting to be able to do a full fingerprint read, but would be nice to try.

So question is, is it possible to get a raw read from hardware on the computer and how would I go about listing all devices/sensors installed?

Comment: Have you tried `lshw` (List HardWare)?

Comment: For live monitoring of plugging in devices, I find `udevadm  monitor -k` to be rather helpful.... for monitoring the device action, `usbhid-dump -e` can be quite helpful.  Fingerprint readers generally have rather poor support in most GNU/Linux distros... It's quite possible that the reader will require you to write your own kernel driver.